# Cocoa Mac Find Volume Bootloader Type

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I recently dealt with NSFileManager and its method `mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options`.
Or `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkSpace] getFileSystemInfoForPath: isRemovable: isWritable: isUnmountable: description: type`

I can pull a lot of Information from Volumes such as Names, Dates, and even formats like NTFS or HFS.

I also look at the Diskarbitrary framework which is basically a low level framework for Volume/Disk related stuff.

But I could not pull one single information, which is the most valuable information for me, is the bootloader (BIOS,EFI). I can check if the OS has the NTFS format (Windows most likely) but you can EFI boot Windows on a Mac as well, so I can not say that NTFS always has the BIOS bootloader.

So is there any framework, any way I can pull the bootloader or any information wether it is BIOS or EFI?

I am running bless and if I add the -legacy flag, it will run the firmware using BIOS, otherwise EFI. So I want to check wether the Volume boots with EFI or BIOS to add the flag dynamically.

Any help appreciated.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use host_get_boot_info in `<mach/mach.h>`

here is some code I put together that may work for you. It does need to run in a blessed environment but according to what you said, it shouldn't be a problem from you.

```
host_t myHost = mach_host_self();
host_priv_t privileged;
kern_return_t rtn = host_get_host_priv_port(myHost, &privileged);
if (rtn == KERN_SUCCESS) {
    kernel_boot_info_t info;
    rtn = host_get_boot_info(privileged, (char *)&info);
    if (rtn == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        printf("boot info: %s\n", info);
    } else {
        printf("error %d\n", rtn);
    }
} else {
    printf("error %d\n", rtn);
}
```

Personally, on my machine, I always get a blank string for info because its implementation varies between machines (so it might be unimplemented on mine) but maybe I'll have pointed you in the right direction.

You may also have some luck with `sysctl` but I couldn't find anything related.